# Decrete Fourier Transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

I am asked to write an fft mix radix in matlab, but before that I want to let to do a discrete Fourier transform in a straight forward way. So I decide to write the code according to the formula defined as defined in wikipedia.

[Sorry I'm not allowed to post images yet]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

So I wrote my code as follows:

```
%Brutal Force Descrete Fourier Trnasform
function [] = dft(X)

%Get the size of A
NN=size(X);
N=NN(2);
%====================

%Declaring an array to store the output variable
 Y = zeros (1, N)
%=========================================



for k = 0 : (N-1)
    st = 0; %the dummy in the summation is zero before we add
    for n = 0 : (N-1)
        t = X(n+1)*exp(-1i*2*pi*k*n/N);
        st = st + t;
    end
    Y(k+1) = st;
end
Y
%=============================================
```

However, my code seems to be outputting a result different from the ones from this website:
http://www.random-science-tools.com/maths/FFT.htm

Can you please help me detect where exactly is the problem?

Thank you!

============
Never mind it seems that my code is correct....

Answer (score 0):

By default the calculator in the web link applies a window function to the data before doing the FFT. Could that be the reason for the difference? You can turn windowing off from the drop down menu.

BTW there is an FFT function in Matlab